# Accessing C arrays in cython wrapped C code from Python

Tags: cython

I have successfully wrapped some of the api functions of a C library with Cython.  I would now like to expose some of the global C arrays used within the library but I am having a tough time figuring out how to do it.

The array pointer is initialized and allocated inside epanet.c:

```
void initpointers()
{
    H = NULL;
}

int  allocdata()
{
    n = MaxNodes + 1; 
    H = (double *) calloc(n, sizeof(double));
}
```

It is made global in a header file (vars.h):

```
extern double   *H;
```

I can access the values in the array within the C code of course by doing something like:

```
for (i=1; i<=Nnodes; i++)
{
    H[i] = some_value;
}
```

I would like to write a function in my pyepanet.pyx file like:

```
def printH(int Nnodes, double *H):
    for i in range(1, Nnodes+1):
        print H[i]
```

but, I am missing the necessary connection between C and cython/python.  I have searched quite a bit for an answer but with no luck.  Please help.

Comment: This page on Cython memoryviews might help: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: I have read over that one several times but I am still not sure how to do it.  I have also read most of Kurt Smith's Cython book.  I just can't find the right examples of wrapping C code that seem to apply to my situation.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#referencing-c-header-files ? Do you just need `cdef extern from "vars.h":\n  double* H` in your pyx file?

Comment: @DavidW, Thanks for your comment.  I am now getting another error that I am working through.  I will let you know if your comment solved my problem.

Comment: I used:  `cdef extern from "lib/vars.h":
    double *H` like you said.  I am now getting the error:  Cannot convert Python object argument to type 'double *' at the line:  `def printH(int Nnodes, double *H):`

Comment: I fixed that error but now since I am referencing vars.h, I am getting redefinition errors.  Arghhh.  Can anyone point me to an example project where someone has successfully wrapped a C library and exposed array pointers so they can iterate on them?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that works.  It seems that I can declare the pointer without referring to the header file.  When I was trying to refer to the header file before, I think I was getting errors due to redefining items.  Here is the code from my .pyx file that works now:

```
cdef:
    extern double *H
    extern int Nnodes

def printH():
    cdef int i
    for i in range(1,Nnodes+1):
        print round(H[i], 2)
```